# What is the difference between Windows-1252 and ANSI encoding?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, ansi

I'm trying to convert **UTF-8** to **ANSI** encoding through a tool.
But it shows **Western European (Windows)-1252** instead of **ANSI**.

Are they both the same thing? Should I go ahead with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What is the difference between Windows-1252 and ANSI encoding?

See below. In practice it probably won't make much difference to your conversion.

If you keep a copy of the original file then you can always apply a different conversion if necessary.

Having said that there are ways of [converting UTF-8 to ANSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130214/how-to-convert-a-batch-file-stored-in-utf-8-to-something-that-works-via-another).

---

#### Windows-1252

> This character encoding is a superset of ISO 8859-1 in terms of printable characters, but differs from the IANA's ISO-8859-1 by using displayable characters rather than control characters in the 80 to 9F (hex) range. Notable additional characters include curly quotation marks and all the printable characters that are in ISO 8859-15. It is known to Windows by the code page number 1252, and by the IANA-approved name "windows-1252".

...

> Historically, the phrase "ANSI Code Page" (ACP) is used in Windows to refer to various code pages considered as native. The intention was that most of these would be ANSI standards such as ISO-8859-1. Even though Windows-1252 was the first and by far most popular code page named so in Microsoft Windows parlance, the code page has never been an ANSI standard. Microsoft explains, "The term ANSI as used to signify Windows code pages is a historical reference, but is nowadays a misnomer that continues to persist in the Windows community.

Source [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

Note that is spite of the above statement by Microsoft they still call Windows 1252 "ANSI":

> [image]

Source [Code Page 1252 Windows Latin 1 (ANSI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195054.aspx)

Comment: so, there won't be difference in conversion. good explaination. thank you

Comment: If you read the first bit of the answer again you will see that there *may* be a difference "differs from the IANA's ISO-8859-1 by using displayable characters rather than control characters in the 80 to 9F (hex) range" - it depends on exactly what characters are in your input.

Comment: i'm asked to finish my project through windows notepad encoding. hope you now understand what type of encoding i'm looking for.

Comment: You could use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), it has build in encoding conversion from UTF-8 to ANSI :)

Answer (score 1):

##### *Are Windows-1252 and ANSI the same thing?*

– Yes, for *Western European* languages, they are identically the same
encodings.
<sup>1</sup>

For other natural languages, see my table at the end of
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1744158).

Unfortunately, the Wikipedia pages on the topic, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and
[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), 
are riddled with confusing statements and unreferenced claims.

You are much better off going directly to
[one of the sources](https://web.archive.org/web/20150204175931/http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/8/56803da0-e4a0-4796-a62c-ca920b73bb17/21-Unicode_WinXP.pdf) that Wikipedia *does* reference. 
It was written in May 2002 and says :

> *The term “ANSI” as used to signify Windows code pages is a
> historical reference, but is nowadays a misnomer that continues to
> persist in the Windows community.
> The source of this comes from the fact that the Windows code page 1252
> was originally based on an ANSI draft, which became ISO Standard
> 8859-1.
> However, in adding code points to the range reserved for control codes
> in the ISO standard, the Windows code page 1252 and subsequent
> Windows code pages originally based on the ISO 8859-x series deviated
> from ISO.
> To this day [May 2002], it is not uncommon to have the development
> community, both within and outside of Microsoft, confuse the 8859-1
> code page with Windows 1252, as well as see “ANSI” or “A” used to
> signify Windows code page support.*

### References

- [Charts showing the Windows-1252 character set | Section 4](https://superuser.com/a/1745441)
- [Post containing a table of all ten Windows code pages](https://superuser.com/a/1744158)
- [Windows-1252 | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)
- [ISO/IEC 8859-1 | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)
- [Unicode and Windows XP | Cathy Wissink, Microsoft](https://web.archive.org/web/20150204175931/http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/8/56803da0-e4a0-4796-a62c-ca920b73bb17/21-Unicode_WinXP.pdf)

---

<sup>1</sup>
For *charts* displaying the Windows-1252 character set,
see [this post, Section 4](https://superuser.com/a/1745441).