# Stop VS Code from auto guessing encoding

Tags: visual-studio-code, character-encoding, utf-8, ansi

I use VS Code to make a German site.
I use a German special character in a `style.css` file.
After restarting VS Code and changing the file encoding from UTF-8 to
Windows-1252, I get what is shown in the image below.
My Auto Guess Encoding is unchecked and the default encoding is UTF-8.
How can I stop the auto-change encoding?
My VS Code version of 1.32.3 and I use windows 10.

[image: screenshot_showing_character_and_encoding]

Comment: Did you check that the file is actually using UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: yes, I checked and files.autoGuessEncoding is false. If i change encoding UTF-8 or open a new file which encoding UTF-8 and write German Language and restarted my vs editor it change form UTF-8 to windows 1252. but if i do not use German special character then its not be change. @Seth

Answer (score 4):

> ##### *How can I stop the auto-change encoding?*

– According to [your own
comment](https://superuser.com/q/1419830#comment2144626_1419830),
the *Auto Guess Encoding* is already *off*. 
The fact that VS Code encodes your file as **Windows-1252**
(**code page 1252** or **CP1252**)  
calls for some other explanation.

By assuming that you have a VS Code setting that specifically decodes
your CSS files 
as being **Windows-1252**,
I've been able to reproduce your situation very accurately.
<sup>1</sup>

### 1. Reproducing the whole scenario

I use a [simplified version of your `style.css`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/henk9/Henke/main/SuperUser-Q1419830/style.css),
containing just a single line :

```
/* Ü */
```

To make VS Code open the file with encoding **Windows-1252**
(with Auto Guess Encoding *off*), 
I assume that the VS Code `settings.json` contains
the following code/line :
<sup>2</sup>

```
"[css]": {"files.encoding": "windows1252"},
```

Such a setting will make VS Code encode all `.css` files as
**Windows-1252**.
<sup>3</sup>

If you download [`style.css`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/henk9/Henke/main/SuperUser-Q1419830/style.css), then right-click it and
*Open with Code*, expect to see :

[image: With encoding Windows-1252, Ü is shown as Ãœ.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

The reason you see *two* **Windows-1252** characters – `Ãœ` – instead
of the *single* **UTF-8** `Ü` character, is that **Windows-1252**
*reads each byte* as a single character – the non-ASCII characters
`Ã` and `œ`. 
**UTF-8** on the other hand uses *two bytes* to read a single
non-ASCII character like `Ü`.
<sup>4</sup>

#### 1. a. How to display `Ü` correctly

To make the German letter `Ü` appear correctly, you need to click : 
*Reopen with Encoding > **UTF-8** Guessed from content*.

[image: 'Reopen with Encoding' changes how the file is decoded.]

Choosing **Reopen with Encoding** *doesn't* change the file itself. 
It changes how the file is *displayed* in VS Code – how it is
*decoded*.

#### 1. b. What you should *not* do

You'll get a problem if you instead click : 
***Save with Encoding** > **UTF-8** Guessed from content*.

[image: Save with Encoding > **UTF-8 changes the file itself.]

This *does* change the file – all *non*-ASCII characters get
*converted* to their corresponding UTF-8 characters.
If you save the file, it is saved with these changes.

When you now close and reopen `style.css`,
it will again be *encoded* as **Windows-1252**. 
(Why? – Because that's exactly what the line
`"[css]": {"files.encoding": "windows1252"},` in `settings.json`
is telling VS Code!)

Here is what you'll see.

[image: Save with Encoding > **UTF-8 changes the file itself.]

Note how `ÃƒÅ“` are the same characters as those displayed in
the screenshot of your question.

The reason you now see *four* characters instead of *two* is the same
as before. 
– The *single* **UTF-8** character `Ã` (2 bytes) is displayed as the
*two* characters `Ãƒ` (still 2 bytes) when decoded with
**Windows-1252**. 
And the single **UTF-8** character `œ` is displayed as the two
**Windows-1252** characters `Å“`.

This completes my reproduction of your scenario.

### 2. How to repair the corrupted file

Given that you want to display `Ü` and not the corrupted `ÃƒÅ“`,
you need to : \

1. convert the file back,
2. encode with **UTF-8**,
3. close and reopen the file.

##### 1. Convert the file back

Here is how to convert the corrupted `style.css` back to its original
state. 
Starting from the previous screenshot, in the status bar,
click **Windows 1252**, 
then *Reopen with Encoding*, and finally **UTF-8**.

[image: Windows 1252 > Reopen with Encoding > UTF-8.]

Expect to see `Ãœ`.
The file is still corrupted, so now *convert* it to **Windows-1252**
by clicking : 
**UTF-8 > *Save* with Encoding > Windows 1252**.

[image: UTF-8 > Save with Encoding > Windows 1252.]

The file has now been converted back to its original state. 
What remains is to *decode* it correctly (with **UTF-8**).

##### 2. Encode with UTF-8

In `settings.json`, delete
`"[css]": {"files.encoding": "windows1252"},`.

##### 3. Close and reopen the file

Close and reopen `style.css`.
Check that you see **UTF-8** in the status bar.
Expect to see :

[image: The corrupted file has been restored.]

Yay! Mission accomplished.

### 3. Encoding vs converting in Notepad++

To better understand the difference between *decoding/encoding* and
*converting* a file, it might help to see how this is done in
another versatile text editor: [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/). 
[This helpful answer](https://superuser.com/a/762475) explains the difference in an
instructive picture :

[image: The difference between Encoding and Converting in Notepad++.]

*Encoding* in Notepad++ corresponds to ***Reopen** with Encoding*
in VS Code, whereas 
*Converting* in Notepad++ corresponds to
***Save** with Encoding* in VS Code.

### 4. ASCII, ANSI, and UTF-8

A few facts may help the understanding of what [ASCII](https://www.bibase.com/images/ascii.gif),
[ANSI](https://superuser.com/a/1744158), and [UTF-8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/UTF-8) are.

- An ASCII character uses just a single byte. 
  Or if you will, it uses seven of the eight bits of a byte
  – the most significant bit is always zero. 
  This corresponds to 0-127 in decimal numbers,
  0x00-0x7F in hex numbers, 
  and 0000 0000 - 0111 1111 in bits.
- Both ANSI/Windows-1252 and UTF-8 encode an ASCII character as the
  ASCII character itself. 
  For example, the character (letter) `k` is a pure ASCII character.
  This is *one byte* (eight bits) which has the decimal number 107,
  the hex number is 0x6B, in bits 0110 1011. 
  As a consequence, it's wrong to say that the ASCII character `k` is
  *not* an ANSI character, nor that it's *not* a UTF-8 character.
  – It's both! 
  If a text file contains *only* ASCII characters, then the ANSI and
  UTF-8 encodings coincide. 
  You *cannot* tell one apart from the other.
  Such a file is *both* ANSI *and* UTF-8 encoded.
  <sup>5</sup>

[image: The windows-1252 (CP-1252) encoding table.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

The upper half of the **Windows-1252** table above corresponds to
numbers 0-127, and the lower half to numbers 128-255.
The latter are the non-ASCII **ANSI** characters of **Windows-1252**.

---

The picture below is taken from
[UTF-8 and ASCII character charts](https://design215.com/toolbox/ascii-utf8.php), 
and displays all those **Windows-1252** characters once more,
numbered 128-255.

[image: The windows-1252 (CP-1252) non-ASCII characters.]

---

If you want to know how many bytes (and *what* bytes) a UTF-8
character uses, try [this online tool](https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-utf8-to-hexadecimal).

### References

- [style.css | containing only `/* Ü */`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/henk9/Henke/main/SuperUser-Q1419830/style.css)
- [Post citing Cathy Wissink, Microsoft](https://superuser.com/a/1748496)
- [Each non-ASCII UTF-8 character uses *at least* two
  (up to four) bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9533324)
- [American Standard Code for Information Interchange table](https://www.bibase.com/images/ascii.gif)
- [Answer to what ANSI is | table in Section 3](https://superuser.com/a/1744158)
- [Unicode Transformation Format - 8 bits explained](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/UTF-8)
- [The Windows-1252 (CP-1252) encoding table](https://dev.to/zenulabidin/lab-easiest-encoding-and-character-sets-guide-4ppg#why-all-the-iso-names)
- [Notepad++ | download page](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/)
- [How to convert ANSI to UTF-8 in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/a/762475)
- [UTF-8 and ASCII character charts](https://design215.com/toolbox/ascii-utf8.php)
- [Converter, UTF-8 to bytes (hexadecimal)](https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-utf8-to-hexadecimal)

---

<sup>1</sup>
I think the scenario I present plausibly describes what *might*
have happened. 
Of course, I cannot know for sure what caused your situation.

<sup>2</sup>
To open `settings.json`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (comma),
and then click the *Open Settings* icon in the top right corner :

[image: Open Settings (JSON)]

On macOS, use <kbd>⌘</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

<sup>3</sup>
[The term “ANSI” as used to signify Windows code pages is a historical
reference […]](https://superuser.com/a/1748496). 
Microsoft still uses *ANSI for Western Europe* interchangeably with
**Windows-1252**, for example in their `notepad.exe` text
editor, typically located at `C:\WINDOWS\System32`.
This is the convention I follow as well.
See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1744158).

<sup>4</sup>
To be more precise, [each non-ASCII UTF-8 character uses *at least*
two (up to four) bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9533324).

<sup>5</sup>
Suppose you have a text file containing *only* pure ASCII characters.
If you open that file in some text editor, and the status bar says
ANSI, that doesn't mean the file is *not* UTF-8 encoded.
It just means that this text editor uses ANSI as its *default*
encoding.
If the default encoding were UTF-8, the editor would display UTF-8 in
the status bar *for the same file*.