# My text file is riddled with question marks. How can I make it readable?

Tags: visual-studio-code, character-encoding, utf-8, ansi

When I open one of my text files in [*Visual Studio Code*](https://code.visualstudio.com/download),
the text contains a lot of question marks where I had expected to see
Swedish letters, such as å, ä, ö :

[image: My text file is riddled with question marks.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

Down to the right (in the status bar of *VS Code*), I've noticed that
it says **UTF-8**.
Is this somehow related to the problems I'm facing?

---

*How can I make all these letters appear correctly?*

---

As a side note, when I open the same file in plain old
[*Windows Notepad*](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-notepad/9MSMLRH6LZF3?hl=en-us),
the text displays correctly :

[image: My text file displays correctly in Notepad.]

In this case, instead of UTF-8, the status bar says **ANSI** at the
bottom right.

But in VS Code, even if I click on **UTF-8**, and then on
*Reopen with Encoding*, I cannot find any encoding by the name ANSI.

[image: VS Code: UTF-8 > Reopen with Encoding > there is no ANSI!]

In case you want to reproduce the behavior with the exact file I've
been using, [here it is](https://user.it.uu.se/%7Ehesc0353/se/Basinkomst.md).

### References

- [Download page for *Visual Studio Code*](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)
- [*Windows Notepad*](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-notepad/9MSMLRH6LZF3?hl=en-us)
- [Basinkomst.md](https://user.it.uu.se/%7Ehesc0353/se/Basinkomst.md)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> #### *How can I make all these letters appear correctly?*

I can think of two options :

1. Convert the file to **UTF-8**. – This is what I recommend.
2. Configure VS Code to auto-detect the most proper encoding.

The second option is preferable
*if you **never** want to change the encoding of any files*.

#### Option 1. Convert the file to UTF-8

The acronym **ANSI** stands for
[American National Standards Institute](https://www.cogoport.com/shipping-terms/american-national-standards-institute-ansi-108).

The problem with **ANSI** encoding is that – although the name
suggests that it's following a standard – it is *conditional*
on what natural language the text is written in. 
In the case of Western European (Latin) languages,
"**ANSI**" encoding means the code page **Windows-1252**.
<sup>1</sup>

#### 1a. Make VS Code use the correct encoding

In VS Code, instead of looking for **ANSI** encoding,
look for **Windows-1252**. 
I clicked **UTF-8** > *Reopen with Encoding*, and VS Code
displayed 
"**Western (Windows 1252)** Guessed from content" as its
top suggestion.

[image: VS Code correctly guesses the encoding is Windows 1252.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

VS Code correctly guessed the encoding **Windows 1252**. 
If you *don't* want to change the encoding, you're now all set and
done.

Otherwise, it remains to *convert* the file to **UTF-8** encoding.

#### 1b. Convert to UTF-8

The status bar now displays **Windows 1252** instead of **UTF-8**. 
Click on **Windows 1252** and then on *Save with Encoding* :

[image: Click Windows 1252 > Save with Encoding.]

Now click on "**UTF-8** utf8" :

[image: Click on UTF-8.]

This *converts* the file's non-ASCII characters to **UTF-8** *and*
encodes the file as **UTF-8**.

#### Option 2. Configure VS Code to auto-detect the encoding

If you *don't* want to convert to **UTF-8**, and if you experience
this problem every time you open another file –
you may prefer to set VS Code to *always* auto-guess the encoding.

To achieve this, you need to enable the **Auto Guess Encoding**
feature of VS Code. 
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
<sup>2</sup>
(comma) and paste or type `autoGuessEncoding`.
Check the box where it says : 
"When enabled, the editor will attempt to guess the character set
encoding when opening files.
This setting can also be configured per language.
Note, this setting is not respected by text search.
Only Files: Encoding is respected."
<sup>3</sup>

[image: Check the box to make VS Code to auto-guess the encoding.]

#### 3. The confusion about what "ANSI" encoding means

Searching the internet to find out what "ANSI" means in the context of
encoding may cause confusion. 
You might encounter that ANSI is ["a misnomer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252),
which is true but, not of much practical help.

What clears up the confusion is to realize that when Microsoft writes
"ANSI" in the status bar of `notepad.exe`,
it typically means **Windows-1252**.
For natural languages other than Western European,
see the table below. 
Other well-known text editors, such as [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads), have
adopted this convention and also write "ANSI" in the status bar.

**Windows-1252** is sometimes called **code page 1252**
or **CP-1252**. Likewise for the other code pages.

| **ANSI** encoding | Language/Alphabet |
| --- | --- |
| Windows-1250 | Slavic languages – Latin alphabet (e.g. Polish) |
| Windows-1251 | Slavic languages – Cyrillic alphabet (e.g. Ukrainian) |
| Windows-1252 | Western European languages (French, German, Scandinavian, Spanish, Swahili …) |
| Windows-1253 | Greek |
| Windows-1254 | Turkish, Latin Azeri, and Latin Uzbek |
| Windows-1255 | Hebrew |
| Windows-1256 | Arabic, Farsi, Urdu |
| Windows-1257 | Baltic languages: Estonian, Latvian, Lithuanian |
| Windows-1258 | Vietnamese |
| Windows-1270 | Sami languages |

### References

- ["ANSI" stands for American National Standards Institute](https://www.cogoport.com/shipping-terms/american-national-standards-institute-ansi-108)
- [Character sets listed by language](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc31654_1251/html/sag/X58457.htm)
- [The code page Windows-1270 | Sami languages](https://zims-en.kiwix.campusafrica.gos.orange.com/wikipedia_en_all_nopic/A/Windows-1270)
- [Microsoft official encoding information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding?view=net-6.0)
- [Windows code pages | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#Windows_emulation_code_pages)
- [Macintosh emulation code pages | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#Macintosh_emulation_code_pages)
- [The default settings in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings)
- [Wikipedia refers to ANSI encoding as "a misnomer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)
- [Download page for Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads)

---

<sup>1</sup>
For a list of what "ANSI" *could* mean, see the table in Section 3.

<sup>2</sup>
On macOS, press <kbd>⌘</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.
For Linux users, "ANSI" typically means Windows-1252 – just as on
Windows. 
For macOS users, try to see what VS Code suggests as
*Guessed from content*. 
Or else have a look at
[Macintosh emulation code pages at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#Macintosh_emulation_code_pages).

<sup>3</sup>
See [the default settings in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings).